# Воспроизвести звук из ресурсов с помощью SoundPlayer

Tags: c++-cli, аудио

Пробовал так:

```
System::IO::Stream^ s = assembly->GetManifestResourceStream("sound.wav");
System::Media::SoundPlayer^ player;
player = gcnew System::Media::SoundPlayer(s);
player->PlayLooping();
```

И так:

```
System::IO::Stream^ s = assembly->GetManifestResourceStream("sound.wav");
System::Media::SoundPlayer^ player;
player = gcnew System::Media::SoundPlayer();
player->Stream = s;
player->PlayLooping();
```

Результат один - никакого звука, и никакой ошибки.  Но, что примечательно при запуске одноразово воспроизводится какой-то системный звук, типа уведомления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью строки `assembly->GetManifestResourceStream` вы получаете поток ресурса, в котором могут содержаться несколько файлов. А нужно получить конкретный файл. Делается это через менеджер ресурсов.

```
Assembly ^assembly = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();

ResourceManager ^rm = gcnew ResourceManager(assembly->GetName()->Name + ".MyForm", assembly);

SoundPlayer ^player = gcnew SoundPlayer(rm->GetStream("sound"));
player->PlayLooping();
```

`MyForm` - это название вашего файла ресурсов. У него расширение `.resx`. В коде название без расширения.

Обратите внимание, что название звукового файла должно быть **без** расширения `.wav` - просто `sound` (как оно показано в визуальном редакторе ресурсов).

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Resources;
using namespace System::Media;
```